# Firebase actionurl domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm confused here. I notice that in order to customize the firebase action url all I will have to do is  change it to my domain like so

> https://example.com/acctmgmt/__/auth/action?mode=&oobCode=.

but my question is when I create the domain do I put any code there or what? because I did change the domain to some website and all it did was just open that specific website.